# Hibernate map of *list* of strings (keyed by string)

Tags: java, hibernate

Have done a bit of reading around this topic and have a solution but am wondering if there is a neater or more optimal solution.

My basic requirement is to create an entity that has a map of lists of type string, ie:

`private Map<String, List<String>> mapOfStringLists;`

It's important that we can query efficiently for entities which contain a specific name-value pair, ie. where `mapOfStringLists.get(K).contains(V)`;

The approach I've taken so far is to create an intermediate entity to represent the mapped items, and then a collection of string elements within this. This necessitates two tables where logically there should only be one (to my mind).

Java code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_USER_PROFILE")
public class UserProfile {
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = UserProfileAttributeMultiValued.class, mappedBy = "userProfile")
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "ATTRIBUTE_NAME")
    private Map<String, UserProfileAttributeMultiValued> attributesMultiValued = new HashMap<>();
}

@Entity(name = "T_USER_PROFILE_ATTRIBUTE_MV")
public class UserProfileAttributeMultiValued {
    @EmbeddedId
    private MultiValuedUserProfileAttributeKey key;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "T_USER_PROFILE_ATTRIBUTE_MV_VALUES", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "USER_PROFILE_GUID_FK"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "ATTRIBUTE_NAME")
    })
    public List<String> values;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_PROFILE_GUID_FK", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private UserProfile userProfile;
}

@Embeddable
public class MultiValuedUserProfileAttributeKey implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "USER_PROFILE_GUID_FK", length = 36)
    private String guid;

    @Column(name = "ATTRIBUTE_NAME")
    private String attributeName;
}
```

Generated schema:

```
    create table T_USER_PROFILE (
        GUID varchar(36) not null,
        primary key (GUID)
    );

    create table T_USER_PROFILE_ATTRIBUTE_MV (
        USER_PROFILE_GUID_FK varchar(36) not null,
        ATTRIBUTE_NAME varchar(255) not null,
        primary key (ATTRIBUTE_NAME, USER_PROFILE_GUID_FK)
    );

    create table T_USER_PROFILE_ATTRIBUTE_MV_VALUES (
        USER_PROFILE_GUID_FK varchar(255) not null,
        ATTRIBUTE_NAME varchar(36) not null,
        values varchar(255)
    );
```

This is reasonably tidy and logical, and I can understand that the intermediate table might be necessary in order to have a clear (compound) primary key for the collection of elements, but perhaps there is a better way lurking?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your requirement. Why don't you normalize the datamodel then you can use JPA to query and not load everything to a map and use the map functions

Comment: Appreciate your reply. By normalise to you mean combine `T_USER_PROFILE_ATTRIBUTE_MV` and `T_USER_PROFILE_ATTRIBUTE_MV_VALUES` in my example? That's exactly what I'd like to do but am struggling to find the right approach. Can you elaborate?